# How to add a rtc node in PPC DTS?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, device-driver, i2c

I'm new in PPC device driver development, and I've recently encountered a problem in DTS.

Our team add a rtc chip rtc-pcf8563 in to the new developing board in PPC platform.
The driver is availiable and right, but I had to add the device in the DTS as a rtc node.
But I don't know how to change the .dts resource.

Here is the code about the .dts, and @3200 is add by me, I don't know whether it could be useful or not.

```
i2c@3000 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    cell-index = <0>;
    compatible = "fsl-i2c";
    reg = <0x3000 0x100>;
    interrupts = <43 2>;
    interrupt-parent = <&mpic>;
    dfsrr;
    rtc@68 {
        compatible = "dallas,ds1339";
        reg = <0x68>;
        };
    };

    i2c@3200 {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    cell-index = <0>;
    compatible = "fsl-i2c";
    reg = <0x3200 0x100>;
    interrupts = <43 2>;
    interrupt-parent = <&mpic>;
    dfsrr;
    rtc@50 {
            compatible = "philips,pcf8563";
            reg = <0x50>;
           };
    };
```

---

Does anyone know how can I change the .dts properly ?